# what is the use of "usleep" in the following code snippet?

Tags: c++

This is the code snippet of a solution for a problem (Problem code: INTEST) asked on codechef. The problem was to process(to find out numbers which are divisible by k ) at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime. The author of this solution initially has declared buffer using this

```
uint8_t g_buffer[256 * 1024];
```

then input has read using

```
read(0, p, sizeof(g_buffer)) //function of unistd.h
```

after this

```
unsigned int i = 0, v;
for (; i < in; ++i) {

    if (pend - p < 16)
    {
        memcpy(pbegin, p, pend - p);

        int r = read(0, pbegin + (pend - p), sizeof(g_buffer) - (pend - p));

        if (r < 32 * 1024) usleep(1000);

        pend = pbegin + (pend - p) + r;
        p = pbegin;
    }

    for (v = 0; *p >= '0' && *p <= '9';++p )
        v = v * 10 + (*p - '0');

    if (*p < '0' || *p > '9') { ++p;
        if (*p < '0' || *p > '9') { ++p;
    }}

    if (v % ik == 0) ++n;

  }
```

Comment: My guess is that the author of the code noticed that read() was returning small amounts of data at a time (or possibly even returning -1 with errno set to EWOULDBLOCK, if stdin is set to non-blocking) and so he put in the usleep() call so that more data would have time to accumulate in stdin's buffer before the next read() call, so that the loop wouldn't spin as much.  I'm not sure that is a worthwhile thing to do, but that would explain the motivation for putting in a sleep call.

Comment: i would like to add one more thing that when i executed the above solution  on commenting "if (r < 32 * 1024) usleep(1000)" i got AC with 0.63 sec and in the other case it was 0.60. i did this for three times.